# Solving an Inequality problem

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, holder-inequality

I have these two problems among other similar question that I haven't figured out how to solve. I believe I could use the AM–GM inequality to solve this but I'm unsure how that would look.

Let $a$ and $b$ be two non-negative real number and let $n$ be a positive integer. Show that

$$(a+b)^n\leq 2^{n-1}(a^n+b^n)$$

Let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be three positive real numbers. Show that

$$\frac{a^3+b^3+c^3}{a^2+b^2+c^2}\geq \frac{a+b+c}{3}$$

Thanks

Comment: What have your tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. In order to get responses that suit your needs, please include **in the body of the question** your own thoughts, the effort made so far, and the specific difficulties that got you stuck.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 1):

AM-GM works for the first inequality if you apply it as the Power Mean Inequality, that is:

$$\sqrt[n]{\frac{a^n+b^n}{2}}\geq \frac{a+b}{2}$$

and raise to the $n$th power. You can also notice that it is direct Holder:

$$(a^n+b^n)(1^n+1^n)\cdot ... \cdot(1^n+1^n) \geq (a+b)^n$$

The second inequality is also a direct application of the Chebyshev Inequality because the sequences $(a,b,c)$ and $(a^2,b^2,c^2)$ are similary ordered, so

$$\frac{1}{3}(a+b+c)\cdot \frac{1}{3}(a^2+b^2+c^2) \leq \frac{1}{3}(a\cdot a^2+b\cdot b^2+c\cdot c^2)$$

implying the desired result. Another idea is to expand the inequality as:

$$2(a^3+b^3+c^3) \geq ab(a+b)+bc(b+c)+ca(c+a)$$

and this can be written as:

$$(a+b)(a-b)^2+(b+c)(b-c)^2+(c+a)(c-a)^2 \geq 0$$

or proven via AM-GM:

$$a^3+a^3+b^3 \geq 3a^2b$$

$$a^3+b^3+b^3 \geq 3ab^2$$

Now sum to get

$$a^3+b^3\geq ab(a+b)$$

and sum cyclically to arrive at the expanded inequality